# How much is a mass production aluminium road bike frame worth?

Tags: road-bike, frames, aluminum

I was just curious, how much is a frame in a entry level road bicycle worth?

In total, what is the cost of a frame per unit in a bicycle built using i.e. a Shimano Sora groupset, white-labelled brakes rims, tubes and tires?

Comment: You can buy framesets separately, have a look at the prices but bear in mind the prices are RRP.

Comment: It's worth whatever someone will pay for it.

Comment: Are you looking for the amount the manufacturer pays for the frame or the number of $ that can be attributed to the frame in a complete build? If the former, with or without paint?

Comment: @jqning good question. I meant the net number of $ attributed to the frame. I could I guess calculate that from adding up all the parts but since I can only use OEM prices (not from the supplier) it won't be an exact calculation. Also, there's a company in Poland that makes custom alu frames within $130 (no paint job), that's cheap, and that's still more expensive than mass production because it's a custom job. Are they too cheap or is the mass prod. really THAT cheap? :)

Comment: As scrap you frame is worth $0.40 / lb.  Yes you can mass produce a aluminum frames very cheap.

Comment: A quick google on "Taiwan bike frame" gives a unit price of $30-40 a frame at 50 units for generic Alu frames. I can imagine when purchasing 1000's of units the suppliers will be getting a better rate than that. So not much.

Comment: That's a good answer, thanks. That makes a good estimation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific way to calculate the worth of a frame when taken from a complete bicycle.  The market will tell you how much it wants to pay for such a frame, but the theoretical calculation of "The frame is worth the complete bike price minus the price of all other components'" is wrong.  Firstly it's wrong because it ignores assembly and value-add pricing.  Secondly it's wrong because it ignores the steep discount you get when buying a complete bike.

Imagine asking how much the chassis of a Ford Explorer is worth.  If you try to buy all the other parts separately, the total will be more than double what a complete vehicle would cost.  Bikes are a bit like that.